# Как сохранять содержимое листа?

Tags: unity3d

Как при переходе между сценами в юнити,делать так,чтоб содержимое листа не исчезало?

Comment: list сделать static , или объект, к которому прикреплен скрипт с листом запускать DontDestroyOnLoad , чтобы при смене сцены объект не убивался и лист сохранялся

Comment: @MikeL, оформите ответом, а не комментарием) а то, вроде и ответа нет - надо бы оставить, но и вы уже правильный дали :D

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [модификатора static](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) делаете list статичным, или объект, к которому прикреплен скрипт с листом [запускать DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) , чтобы при смене сцены объект не убивался и лист сохранялся.